# How to print mysql database print style?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to print 'show databases' cmd style in python:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Any trick to do this?

```py
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    insp = sa.inspect(engine)
    db_list = insp.get_schema_names()
    print(db_list)
```

Comment: There is this gem: [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate), see the `tablefmt` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate) can do this out of the box, see my example with the table from your question.

```py
import tabulate

example_table = [
    {"Database" : "information_schema"},
    {"Database" : "mysql"},
    {"Database" : "performance_schema"},
    {"Database" : "sys"}
]

print(
    tabulate.tabulate(
        example_table, 
        headers={
                k : v 
                for k,v in zip(
                    example_table[0].keys(), 
                    example_table[0].keys()
                )
        },
        tablefmt="psql"
    )
)
```

Prints out

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
|--------------------|
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```